# Capture the name of an input value in a function

Tags: r, dataframe, function, tidyverse, rlang

I was wondering if there is a way to capture the input to the argument `study_id` in my function below.

For example, my desired output in the below example is: `"study"`. Is this possible?

```
library(rlang)

foo <- function(data, study_id){
  
  study_id <- ensym(study_id)
  
# names(data[study_id]) # I tried this without success
}
  
# EXAMPLE OF USE:

dat = data.frame(a=1:3,study=4:6)

foo(dat, study_id = study)

# DESIRED OUTPUT:

> [1] "study"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use [`as_string`](https://rdrr.io/cran/rlang/man/as_string.html)

```
foo <- function(data, study_id){
  
  study_id <- ensym(study_id)
  
  as_string(study_id)
}
```

-testing

```
foo(dat, study_id = study)
[1] "study"
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done with `deparse/substitute`

```
foo1 <- function(data, study_id) deparse(substitute(study_id))
foo1(dat, study_id = study)
[1] "study"
```

Comment: In tidyverse ecosystem what is the meaning of `~` as used in the following: `struct == "HCS" ~ "CMVE"`? I think it mean OR, right?

Comment: @rnorouzian It seems your `~` is applied in `case_when`.  In that case, it will be just a two sided formula expression - saying for the logical expression on the left of the ~, the value is "CMVE".  For other cases, i.e. `map(1:5, ~ )`, it is a lambda function i.e. `function(x) x` created on the fly